# Display WordPress-ACF value from a user profile in frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, advanced-custom-fields

I want to create a page with all the user profiles, but i only want to display the images they defined in the Advanced Custom Fields on their user profiles.

I tried to do something like this:

```
<?php if (is_page(9)){ ?>   
<section class="pageContent contentWidth">
<ul class="profilePictures">
<?php
    $blogusers = get_users('orderby=nicename&role=subscriber');
    foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
        echo '<li><div class="image_wrapper"><img class="profile1" src="';
        $user->the_field('profilbild');
        echo '"/></div><img class="profile2 hoverShow" src="';
        $user->the_field('funbild');
        echo '"/><div class="imageOverlay"><p>';
        $user->the_field('nickname');
        echo '</p></div></li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
</section>
<?php } ?>
```

But what i'm getting in frontend is only:

```
<section class="pageContent contentWidth">
<ul class="profilePictures">
<li><div class="image_wrapper"><img class="profile1" src="
```

and then it ends.

Edit: The error is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_User::the_field() in
>   .../index.php on line 208

This is the line of

> $user->the_field('profilbild');

So I seems like I can't call this method from there.
But how can I do it then?

Edit2:
So I found the solution for the method not found error. I'm just echoing out the shortcodes for the fields now:

```
echo '<li><div class="image_wrapper"><img class="profile1" src="
[acf field="profilbild"]
"/></div><img class="profile2 hoverShow" src="
[acf field="funbild"]
"/><div class="imageOverlay"><p>
[acf field="nickname"]
</p></div></li>';
```

But it fails at locating the right user I think. ACF doesn't know which user to go to.

What would be a solution for this?

Comment: set wp_debug = true in your wp-config.php file and then check whats stopping your code .

Comment: i did this and edited my question with the results.

Comment: var_dump($user); before foreach what it outputs ?

Comment: before foreach it is NULL, afterwards it dumps out the user object, as expected.

I think the problem might be, that the acf plugin doesn't know whith user to go to.

Comment: mybad i meant
 
var_dump($blogusers); just to check it is not null,

Comment: it isn't. Does exactly what it should do. Puts out the array of users it found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was the following:

```
$image1 = get_field('profilbild', $user);
$image2 = get_field('funbild', $user);
$name = get_field('nickname', $user);
echo '<li><div class="image_wrapper"><img class="profile1" src="';
echo $image1['url'];
echo '"/></div><img class="profile2 hoverShow" src="';
echo $image2['url'];
echo '"/><div class="imageOverlay"><p>';
echo "$name";
echo '</p></div></li>';
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for this solution! It's also a great solution for displaying the post author's custom information. Well done schliflo!